# Which Jetty distribution to download to run a full blown Spring3.0 app?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jetty

I have noticed, that as of V7.x, there are [two stand-alone distributions](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Starting/Downloads) of Jetty. A Codehouse and an Eclipse distribution. Which one do I need to download if I want to run a full-blown Spring 3.0 (incl. Spring MVC/Webflow/Security, Annotations, Hiberate, REST, JSF, Comet ...) application? How to add missing depedencies?

Since I would like to run Jetty stand-alone, please no maven suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, I don't understand why you leave out maven. There is a [maven jetty plugin](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Maven+Jetty+Plugin) for example.

As for the dependencies - well, add them to `WEB-INF/lib`. Or let maven build your .war file by specifying `<packaging>war</packaging>` in your pom.xml. All the maven dependencies will be filled in the `WEB-INF/lib` folder.

Back to the question title - Eclipse's distribution is, as it seems, based on OSGi. If you are not familiar with OSGi, go for the codehaus edition.

Comment: I want jetty to run on a remote server and just deploy my war to it. What do I need maven for this task?

Comment: well, than use maven for dependency management only (although you can use a cargo plugin to deploy remotely as well)

Comment: actually, I already make it so. I just don't want to make use of maven to start jetty on the server.

Comment: One more question: Since all guys here still suggest using maven for this task - what if I want to run several apps on one server? Would you start one jetty instance per app?

Answer (score 1):

the  [Jetty@eclipse](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/) is the core Jetty Web Server:

```
*  Core Jetty Web Server (HTTP & Websocket)
* Core Jetty Servlet Container
* JNDI, JMX, OSGi, JASPI modules
* HTTP Client
```

the [Jetty@codehaus](http://dist.codehaus.org/jetty/) also supports EE features such as JSP, spring etc:

```
*  Hightide Application Server (Jetty WebServer plus EE features)
* Jetty with non-eclipse modules: JSP, spring, terracotta, openspaces, etc.
* Jetty Maven plugin
* debian, RPM distributions
* Older jetty releases
```

From my experience its best to add dependencies to the pom.xml, 
and build with maven using `mvn jetty:run`

Answer (score 0):

You can use maven to set up a functional environment with all possible jars included.  You can then handpick those you actually need and leave out those you don't.